Minimum number of negative clues for a 9 x 9 Sudoku
It is known that an ordinary Sudoku with a unique solution must have at least 17 clues. A clue is a statement that a particular cell (i, j) must contain a particular value k.
But we could also consider "negative clues". A negative clue is a statement that a particular cell (i, j) does not contain a particular value k. What is the minimum number of negative clues that suffice to uniquely specify a completed Sudoku grid?
It is clear that 136 negative clues suffice, because we can start with a Sudoku that has 17 clues, and replace each (positive) clue with 8 negative clues. But this process generates some redundant clues, so the actual answer is less than 136.
I don't know the answer to this, and I strongly suspect that it's an unsolved problem. I have a feeling that someone must have studied this problem before, but I don't know what to search for.
Edit: Thanks to noedne for pointing out that this variant is called Pencilmark Sudoku, or Sukaku. I also found that "eliminations" is a better term than "negative clues". It appears that the lowest known number of eliminations for a puzzle with a unique solution is 86.

Can you please explain what you mean by "this process generates some redundant clues", with an example? And although they are called 'clues' they are not: they are the actual answers.

@WeatherVane: As a simple example, if one box of a conventional puzzle would contain given digit 1 at position X and given digit 2 at position Y, replacing 1 with "Digit X is none of {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} would imply that digit X contained a 1, and therefore no other digit in that box could be a 1.  Replacing the digit 2 with "This digit is none of {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} would redundantly specify that digit Y cannot be 1, even though that would be implied by the fact that digit X couldn't be anything other than 1.

But isn't this a solving method? As the deleted answer said, how can using a different notation method lead to more redundancy than the known minimum?

@WeatherVane It is conceivable that replacing a clue of the form "this cell is $1$" with a weaker clue "this cell is not $2$, $5$, or $9$" could still yield a unique solution.

But in effect, isn't this adding more than the 17 minimum numbers to the initial grid, which has redundancy?

I found the name of this variant: Sukaku (also Pencilmark Sudoku). People have indeed sought low-clue puzzles, including this person who claims to have puzzles with 86 clues.

@noedne which is the opposite of OP's proposal. Its cells contain several possibilities, not "nots".
